# mysql_fetch_assoc lost one value

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code:

```
function get_team_a($id_team){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = '{$id_team}'");
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

In table i have 3 columns:

```
ppl op  id
10  23  1006
6   21  1005
11  15  1004
```

But when i do that:

```
$team_zgl= get_team_a($team_id); 
<br><b>'.$team_zgl['id'].' </b>
```

i have nothing but this works:

```
<br><b>'.$team_zgl['op'].' </b>
<br><b>'.$team_zgl['ppl'].' </b>
```

What the?!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Why don't you try doing a `var_dump` of `$team_zgl`?

Comment: obvious question. is there an `id` field in this table?

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` only fetches one row at a time.

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
return $rows;
```

This will return a multi-dimensional array of the rows which you can then iterate over.

If not even one row is being returned you probably have a syntax error in your query.

---

Your code is vulnerable to injection. You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO/mysqli

Comment: What is the point of '{$id_team}' ? Shouldn't it be like just $id_team ? (if it's an INT)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld `{$id_team}` is valid PHP string variable interpolation syntax

Comment: at a guess I would say there is only one row with id='something'

Comment: @ExplosionPills - ok, actually I've never used it. Is there any reason for using that syntax? I'm just curious.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld what syntax?

Comment: @ExplosionPills - {$id_team} - with brackets like that

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld in this case it's personal preference, but you can't interpolate method calls without the brackets and array access works differently